# how do i ignore the backticks in codeigniter when using active records? i need to order by cases

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how do i ignore the backticks in codeigniter when using active records? i need to order by cases

```
case when roll_number is null then 1 else 0 end,
```

which code igniter makes it as

```
ORDER BY `case` when roll_number is null then 1 else 0 end
```

which gives me an error. Please help

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Post some code where you are getting the error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers...

I figured out that in active records when using `$this->db->order_by()` you can't skip the backticks.

So ended up using `$this->db->query($sql);` where I assigned my normal mysql query to the `$sql` variable

Comment: We can make this work by add this line just before the query starting $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false; Already comment by @stalin

Answer (score 13):

This could be a little old, but for someone who is looking for an answers you could add

`$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;`

be aware that this will remove all backticks on this query

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: This is the cide i have used for ordering:$this->db->order_by('case when roll_number is null then 1 else 0 end, CASE WHEN roll_number like "%-%" THEN roll_number END, CASE WHEN roll_number not like "%-%" THEN CAST( trim(roll_number) AS SIGNED ) END'),'asc',FALSE);