# Mysql Ordering by field value CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to filter data from DB according to user sex-orientation and location.

However because there are entries that are set to target all sexes, I want the results to be shown on the top of the page the most relevant and then the less relevant. If the user is a female she should see the first results the ones target by female, and then the other ones.

```
  $data['sex'] = $this->model_user->getUserSex($user);
  $data['age'] = $this->model_user->getUserAge($user);
  $data['location'] = $this->model_user->getUserLoc($user);

  $where = "(target_sex = '".$data['sex']."' AND location='".$data['location']."') OR  (target_sex = 'all' AND location='".$data['location']."')";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->limit(3);
        $order = "CASE WHEN target_sex = '".$data['sex']."' THEN  location='".$data['location']."'";

        $this->db->order_by($order); 

        $sql = $this->db->get('toolkit_events');

        if($sql->num_rows() > 0){

            return $sql->result(); 

            }
```

It is showing me a syntax error.

Any help will be really greatfull.

Comment: can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: what error you are getting?? and where have u used the select keyword??/

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080980/how-do-i-ignore-the-backticks-in-codeigniter-when-using-active-records-i-need-t

Comment: this is the error: "Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN target_sex = 'male-gay' THEN location='London' LIMIT 3' at line 4

SELECT * FROM (`toolkit_events`) WHERE (target_sex = 'male-gay' AND location='London') OR (target_sex = 'all' AND location='London') ORDER BY `CASE` WHEN target_sex = 'male-gay' THEN location='London' LIMIT 3

"