# how to use external database table in codeigniter active records

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am facing below problem. Have to fetch a row from database which is not default db. i am querying like  `->from("database_name.table_name")`, but its been converted as  ``` ->from("``database_name``.``table_name``") ``` as gives error. How to correct this please. Thank You!

Comment: explore your question. may be you have not load your second database.

Comment: @NomanJaved You do not need to specifically load another DB if it is on the same server. vikram have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080980/how-do-i-ignore-the-backticks-in-codeigniter-when-using-active-records-i-need-t

Answer (score 1):

Connect to second database in databse file. Load second database like this.

```
$DB2=$this->load->database($config, TRUE);    
//then execute the query.
```

Also follow this link.
[Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619711/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections?rq=1)
Hope this will help you.