# Codeigniter is adding backticks (``) / tilde symbol automatically in sql query in date format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

** Backticks (tilde symbol) is adding automatically iniside date 
    format in sql query in Codeigniter:**

```
$this->db->select("DISTINCT(b.dname),DATE_FORMAT(atime,' %d %M %Y 
%h:%i:%s') as at");
$this->db->join('rb b','b.list_id = al.afid','LEFT');
$this->db->from('rfal al');
$this->db->where('al.afid ='.$fileid);
$this->db->where('al.is_back',1);
$this->db->order_by('at','DESC');
$this->db->limit(5);
$query= $this->db->get();

**Will Get an error as follows**  
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that   
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use   
near ':%i:%s') as accessed_time FROM (`rfal` al) LEFT JOIN  at line 1  

SELECT DISTINCT(b.dname), DATE_FORMAT(atime, `'` %d %M %Y %h:%i:%s')   
as at FROM (`rfal` al) LEFT JOIN `rb` b ON `b`.`l_id` =   
`al`.`afid` WHERE `al`.`afid` =1106 AND `al`.`is_back` = 1 ORDER BY     
`at` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Please make the question more clear. Include what is the expected behavior? And what is the output. The more clear your question is, the more people will be interested to help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an attempt to post question and answer together, but the answer was included withing the question. And most probably it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Another Solution**

From the docs:

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: nice copy and paste https://stackoverflow.com/a/18081307/4595675

Answer (score 0):

try this line before your query:

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
```

be aware that this will remove all backticks on this query

Comment: Is this a good idea?

Comment: due to CI's singleton pattern this setting will probably stick for the duration of the querying. test if it resets afterwards, if not, set it to true after doing your business. it's a good idea to keep this on.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution as follows:**

In the database configuration file  `./application/config/database.php`
add a new element to array with default settings.

```
$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']= FALSE;
```